# R : Path separator issues when invoking a command with system()

Tags: r, path

I'd like to invoke these commands in R

```
path1 <- "C:/folder1"
path2 <- "C:/folder2" 
command <- paste( "xcopy", path1, path2, "/e /i /h", sep=" " )
command
system(command)
```

The problem is R use / instead of \ as path separator and I obtain this error :

> ```
> Invalid numbers of parameters
> ```

If I execute manually this command in replacing / by \ then it works

How can I do to manage this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: What about using `path1 <- "C:\\folder1"` and `path2 <- "C:\\folder2"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me

path1 <- "F:\\folder1"
path2 <- "F:\\folder2" 
command <- paste( "xcopy", path1, path2, "/e /i /h", sep=" " )
command
system(paste( 'xcopy', path1, path2, '/e /i /h', sep=" " ))

Comment: The backslash needs to be doubled within quotes as per lukeA's comment  below the post.